# How to read a exit code of python file from other python file

Tags: python, exit, exit-code, sys

I am trying to run a `test1.py` from `test_main.py` and read exit code of test1.py

I tried

test1.py

```
import sys,time
print "subfolder"
time.sleep(10)
sys.exit(0)
```

**Try-1**

```
import sys
print "main-1"
import test1 #execfile( "test1.py")
print "main-2"
```

output

```
 main-1
 subfolder
```

missing `main-2`

**Try-2**

```
import sys,os
print "main-1"
os.system( "test1.py")
print "main-2"
```

output

```
main-1
main-2
```

and printing `subfolder` in cmd prompt.

But how can I get exit code of test1 in test_main.py

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need to *invoke the script as a subprocess and get the process exit code* for whatever reason (why not just make the called code a function and `return` your result?), you can use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(['test1.py'])
print retcode
```